# Qual forma segura de verificar se um objeto é numérico?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou implementando alguns funções genéricas em um modulo de meu sistema, e desejo tratar em determinada situação se o registro for numérico (faço cálculos).

Então pesquisando algumas forma de fazer sem ter que comparar com cada tipo numérico separadamente (Ex: `Integer`, `Double`, `Float`, etc), vi que `Number` é um tipo base de todos os outros (até onde pesquisei e entendi), então isso sendo verdade, bastaria fazer a comparação da instância do objeto ao tipo base `Number`, dessa forma:

```
// sendo 'value' um Object
if(value instanceof Number){
    // é uma instância de um valor numérico
} else {
    // NÃO é uma instância de um valor numérico
}
```

Fiz alguns teste, para confirmar se isso está correto e em meus teste parece estar tudo correto, como podem acompanhar [aqui no Ideone](http://ideone.com/NLXxNv).

**Perguntas**

- Está forma cobrirá todos os possíveis tipos de objetos numéricos?
- Está forma está correta?
- Está é a melhor maneira de se fazer essa verificação?

Comment: Sim, sim e sim. Só ficaram de fora o tipo primitivo `char` e sua correspondente classe _wrapper_ `Character`.

Comment: O tipo `char` guarda um número inteiro no intervalo de 0 a 65535. Se é considerado um número para você ou não, vai depender da sua aplicação.

Comment: @Piovezan, esse `char` é tipo um `int` de 16 bits? Pois o `int` é 32 bits e o `long` 64 bits, certo?

Comment: @Piovezan, estava verificando a outra `class` comum entre eles que o `Character` também implementa, que seria `Comparable` (`class Character implements Serializable, Comparable<Character>`), mas está o String também implementa, então a melhor forma de tratar o `Character` junto a verificação é fazendo um `instanceof` extra, algo assim: `(value instanceof Number || value instanceof Character)`?

Comment: Sim, seria um unsigned int de 16 bits. E sim, a melhor forma seria como você sugere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, está forma está correta para verificar se o tipo é um `Number`.

Pode ter outras firulas que podem ajudar em alguns casos específicos, mas basicamente esta é a melhor forma.

Mas note que não cobrirá todos os tipos numéricos. E na verdade, de certa forma, isto não é possível de fato. Obviamente isto apenas verifica se o tipo implementa a `Number`, nada mais que isto. Se alguém criar um tipo numérico que não implemente este tipo, ele não será considerado.

Claro que você verá que é um erro de *design* do tipo numérico em questão. Aí precisa ver se isto é aceitável ou não. Eu acho que é, pra mim, tipos implementados de forma errada não devem ser considerados mesmo. E pode ser que não seja erro, pode ser que tem um bom motivo para fazer desta forma.

De qualquer forma quando herdamos de classes ou implementamos interfaces, estamos dizendo algo relevante ao código. Se existe uma condição externa que agrupe certos tipos e isto não pode ser determinado em código, não faz muito sentido sua utilização em código. E nem sei se deveria existir, mesmo que em documentação.

Por exemplo, o tipo [`Complex`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex.html) do Apache não faz isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O importante a meu ver é que o teste por implementar `Number` cobre os casos em que o compilador faz _boxing_ do tipo primitivo para tipos que poderiam ser usados em operações aritméticas com os operadores normais do Java (+, -, etc.), como acontece nos testes do OP. Fica só `Boolean` de fora.

Comment: Sim, concordo, mas pra falar a verdade eu não considero nem `Boolean`, nem `Character` tipos numéricos. Eles nunca deveriam ser usados como se fossem.

Comment: Concordo, mas desconhecendo a intenção do OP há que se considerar a possibilidade de alguém inadvertidamente usar `Character` ou `char` em uma operação aritmética, coisa que o Java aceita.

Comment: @Piovezan, agora lendo os comentários, surgiu outra duvida, o `char` ou `Character` não deve ser utilizado para valores numéricos? Nunca utilizei ele em minha aplicação! Mas quando você o citou inicialmente o `char` verifiquei na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) e achei que ele era para finalidades similar ao [short do C#, que é um "Inteiro assinado de 16 bits"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ybs77ex4(v=vs.120).aspx), mas pelo que entendi em seus comentários ele não tem essa finalidade? Qual seria sua finalidade?

Comment: Vejamos se entendi bem a pergunta. `Character`/`char` representa um caracter ou símbolo (letra, dígito, símbolo especial, etc.) mas essa representação não passa de um código numérico em uma tabela de codificação (no caso do Java internamente o `char` é armazenado como UTF-16, mas há outras tabelas, como UTF-8, ASCII, ISO-8859-1, etc.), então o que ele guarda é esse valor numérico (código). Por que o Java permite operações aritméticas com ele? Talvez para facilitar a manipulação de caracteres ou para manter compatibilidade com outros tipos numéricos visto que no fundo se trata de um número tbm.

Comment: @Piovezan, mas no caso, o `char` ou `Character`, apesar de "no fundo se trata de um número tbm", não deve ser utilizado como um numero certo? Então pensando assim como o @bigown citou: "mas pra falar a verdade eu não considero nem `Boolean`, nem `Character` tipos numéricos. Eles nunca deveriam ser usados como se fossem". Não faria sentido tratar em minha verificação eles como numéricos (apesar de no fundo serem). Então o correto seria apenas: `value instanceof Number` como o exemplo original da pergunta. Certo?

Comment: Certo, mas você não especificou na questão quais classes de objetos serão testadas, apenas citou que os objetos serão usados em cálculos, por isso eu recomendei a checagem de `Character`/`char` por via das dúvidas. E por isso eu disse em um dos primeiros comentários: "se devem ser considerados números ou não, vai depender da sua aplicação".

Comment: @Fernando é isso mesmo. O Piovezan deu informações adicionais para te ajudar já que você chegou usar um `char` no seu exemplo. Apesar de um caracteres ou um booleano poder ser representado por um número, a semântica não é de um número, não o considere como se fosse um.